# Connect Api from my website and get automatic update of my Dj Charts

Tags: xml, post, soap, methods, get

First thing first HELLO EVERYONE !

Ok i'm newbies in developer area... i'm graphic designer and felt asleep when talking about code. But it's interesting of course. I use Resident Advisor to publicly communicate of my month dj pick tracks... By the past RA give a DJ Box (iFrame) but now they do no support it and give API.

But i honestly pure newbies here with soap, http get/post and how to deal with in a context on my website. I would like to build a Dj chart web page will connect to the API and get automatic update from my RA Dj account.

All is explain here :
http://www.residentadvisor.net/api/dj.asmx?op=getcharts

But i don't know how to do that. Can someone HELP me to get results :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there's probably a solution with angularJS but did someone who know it can help a bit ? at the end of this page :
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

if i put my access token link (http://www.residentadvisor.net/api/dj.asmx/getcharts?AccessKey=MYKEY&UserID=MYUSERID&DJID=MYDJID&Option=1&ChartID=) i can retrieve data. I would like to do the same on a web page. But i would like to choose xml nodes dynamically and CSS styling too.